# Stop Further Rules Processing not working

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, price-rules

I am offering a free gift for people that place a certain minimum order. There are multiple items to choose from, but only 1 is free at a time. I made 2 separate Shopping Cart Price Rules with the Stop Further Rules Processing option set to YES. The problem is that both of the rules are being applied.

How to I get only one of the rules to apply?

See images below.

Thank you,

Both rules are set with different priories.

[image]

Rule MEC refers to the $600 minimum order free gift. This one takes priority over the other.

[image]

Rule 12FT refers to the $300 minimum order free gift. Should not be applied if rule MEC is applied.

[image]

You can see that both the $600 and $300 gifts are applied.

[image]

Comment: Which Magento version are you using? The stop further rules processing does not work on item level on older verisons. See this for further clarification https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix

Answer (score 3):

There are several options, one of the easiest is just add a condition (the second tab) to the second rule to apply for the carts from $300 to $599.